# Bubble Plot in tikz with size depending on value and color defined by a fixed group

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to produce a bubble plot with the following properties.

1. Bubbles with the same x-coordinate have the same color.
2. Bubbles' size depends on the value specified in the data.
3. The areas of all bubbles are inside of the graph.

**EDIT**

The bubbles should also have the additional properties:

4. I can adjust each color for each x-coordinate manually. For example, 1, 5, 8 are blue; 2,3, 9 are red; 4,6,7 are gray. The MWE has a reduced number of x-coordinates to work as a *minimal* worked example.
5. The bubble's size depends on the value specified in the data. This data should appear as number inside the bubble.

Currently, I have this minimal worked example.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          xtick=data,
          symbolic x coords = {A,B,C,D},
          symbolic y coords = {1,2,3,4,5},
          ytick distance=1,ymax=5,
          scale only axis,
          xticklabel style={anchor=north,align=center},
          xticklabels={A,B and C,D,E and F},
       ]
      \addplot[%
          scatter=true,
          only marks,
          point meta=explicit,
          fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1,
          visualization depends on = {2*\thisrow{Val} \as \perpointmarksize},
          scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
          /tikz/mark size=\perpointmarksize,
         % /tikz/mark options={fill=blue!80!black}
          },
          nodes near coords*,
          nodes near coords style={text=white,font=\sffamily,anchor=center},
      ] table [x={Group},y={Posttest},meta index=2] {
Group  Posttest Val 
A  1  2 
A  2  8 
B  2  15 
B 4 10 
C  2  10 
C 5 3
C 3 12
D  1  4 
D 3 11 
};      
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This examples produces the following bubble plot:

[image]

In the worked example, the color depends on size, i.e., the value of column *Val* in the data table, but not on the value of the corresponding x-coordinate.

The area of the blue bubble with *3* and the area of the orange bubble with *11* are outside of the graph.

I tried to alter the color with `% /tikz/mark options={fill=blue!80!black}` but it has no effect. The alteration of `meta index = 2` produces other bubbles which do not have the wished size and color.

I would be very happy for help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          xtick=data,
          enlargelimits=.1,
          symbolic x coords = {A,B,C,D},
          symbolic y coords = {1,2,3,4,5},
          ytick distance=1,ymax=5,
          scale only axis,
          xticklabel style={anchor=north,align=center},
          xticklabels={A,B and C,D,E and F},
       ]
      \addplot[%
          scatter=true,
          only marks,
          point meta=\thisrow{color},
          fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1,
          visualization depends on = {2*\thisrow{Val} \as \perpointmarksize},
          visualization depends on = {\thisrow{Val} \as \Val},
          scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
          /tikz/mark size=\perpointmarksize
         % /tikz/mark options={fill=blue!80!black}
          },
          nodes near coords*={$\pgfmathprintnumber\Val$},
          nodes near coords style={text=white,font=\sffamily,anchor=center},
      ] table [x={Group},y={Posttest}] {
Group  Posttest Val color
A  1  2 .1
A  2  8 .1
B  2  15 .3
B 4 10 .3
C  2  10 .1
C 5 3 .1
C 3 12 .1
D  1  4 .3
D 3 11 .3
};      
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result:
[image]

- Use `enlargelimits` (or `enlarge x limits` and `enlarge y limits`) to control the relation of the axis to the data plots,
- Use `visualization depends on = {\thisrow{Val} \as \Val}` in combination with `nodes near coords*={$\pgfmathprintnumber\Val$}` to control the text inside the bubbles,
- Use `point meta=\thisrow{color}` in combination with the color column to explicitly choose and match the colors.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @HasanZakeri for your answer! Unfortunately, my description of the requirements was not neat enough. How would you alter your solution if (1) the color of, e.g., A and D should be the same, and (2) the number inside the bubble should be the value of the data like in my example plot before?

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect the descriptions.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much!